# Filtering column using input parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, null, case

I need to filter a column based on an outside parameter's value, but I do not know how to handle the NULL case since it requires a different syntax.
What I have is something like this:

```
WHERE c.fruit LIKE
(CASE :fruitParam
    WHEN 'Orange' THEN 'OR'
    WHEN 'Apple' THEN 'APL'
    WHEN 'Any' THEN '%'
    WHEN 'None' THEN NULL  -- doesn't work since we can't do: LIKE NULL
END)
```

In this instance, there are rows that need to be returned where `c.fruit is null`. Is there an alternative way to write this such that when the parameter 'fruitParam' is 'None' we can set the condition: `c.fruit IS NULL`?

This is using Oracle.

Comment: Why can't you use where nvl(c.fruit, 'None) LIKE .... and WHEN 'None' then 'None' or add else 'None'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just move it into another clause:

```
WHERE (c.fruit LIKE
CASE :fruitParam
    WHEN 'Orange' THEN 'OR'
    WHEN 'Apple' THEN 'APL'
    WHEN 'Any' THEN '%'
END)
or (:fruitParam = 'None' and c.fruit is null)
```